# Smarty: Combine two Variables in a Modifier

Tags: variables, smarty, modifier

how to combine two variables(array vals) in a modifier?

this works:

```
<a href="{'smartphone'|buildLink:$k:$v["brand"]}">
```

but this will not??

```
<a href="{'smartphone'|buildLink:$k:$v["brand"]+$v["brand2"]}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Smarty syntax is limited in terms of where expressions are allowed, so you probably will have to assign the sum to a temporary variable:

```
{assign var=_sum value=$v[brand]+$v[brand2]}
<a href="{'smartphone'|buildLink:$k:$_sum}"
```